# Why excerpt is Displaying same in Random Posts list

Tags: posts, excerpt

I am tryping to fetch random posts list in single.php above footer.
Titles of the post displaying randomly and are unique in `<li>` but the excerpt is same for every post title (i.e., same excerpt of post content 'single.php').

First tried this:

```
  <ul class="random-list">
    <?php $posts = get_posts('orderby=rand&numberposts=12'); foreach($posts as $post) { ?>
    <li  class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?><br></a>
    </li>
    <?php } ?>
    </ul>
```

Second try:

```
<ul>
<?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 5, 'orderby' => 'rand', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'offset' => 1);
$rand_posts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $rand_posts as $post ) : ?>
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use the_title() and the_excerpt() functions outside the [wordpress loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop), therefore, they will not work.

I suggest you try something like :

```
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 12, 'orderby' => 'rand', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'offset' => 1);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
while($query->have_posts()){
    $query->the_post();
    // the_excerpt() will now work as expected
}
```

Comment: Worked but number of posts showing only 5 even after changing into numberposts => 12

Comment: I fixed it, use posts_per_page in a WP_Query

Answer (score 0):

Your `get_posts()` function may be causing the error that you interpret now.

You can follow up the standard loop structure so that it will be very easy for you to print the `title()`, content and the excerpt conditions.

```
<?php
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 12, 'orderby' => 'rand', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'offset' => 1);
   $random_posts = new WP_Query($args);
   if($random_posts->have_posts()) : 
      while($random_posts->have_posts()) : 
         $random_posts->the_post();
?>
         <h1><?php the_title() ?></h1>
         <div class='post-content'><?php the_content() ?></div>
         <div class='excerpt'><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>      
<?php
   endwhile;
   else: 
?>
   Oops, there are no posts.
<?php
   endif;
?>
```